# Extract data from html using urllib2 shows error not well-formed (invalid token): line 5, column 62

Tags: html, python-2.7, web-scraping

I have a code to convert currency from Indian ruppee to US dollars amd am using google currency converter api for that,

Code Used:

```
url="https://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=%s&from=%s&to=%s"(total_incl_tax,'INR','USD')

file = urllib2.urlopen(url)
data = file.read()
print "dataaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",data
file.close()
dom = parseString(data)
xmlTag = dom.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].toxml()
xmlData=xmlTag.replace('<span>','').replace('</span>','')
print "dommmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm",xmlData
```

When i used this i get the following error not well-formed (invalid token): line 5, column 62.How do i take data from html and the data is between span tag.Please help?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error while trying to parse the string:

```
dom = parseString(data)
```

It is because the URL mentioned in question is [invalid XML](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Ffinance%2Fconverter%3Fa%3D100%26from%3DINR%26to%3DUSD&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0). However for a [valid XML](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.w3.org/), parser works as expected.

Pro tip: Don't use `urllib2` or `xml.dom.minidom` use requests and beautifulsoup instead.